# Dependency injection with same class name in source links to same object?

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, namespaces

I may be missing something basic, but not sure what to lookup to find out what.

I have a simple program that I expect to return:

```
ImplA
ImplB
```

It actually returns:

```
ImplA
ImplA
```

I know renaming class "Do" in each file, or wrapping the class definition in a namespace, solves the issue, but is there a way for this to work where both files name the implementation the same? Is the some way to limit the class visibility to the file?

```
// main.cpp
#include "do_a.h"
#include "do_b.h"

#include <cstdint>

int32_t main(int32_t,char**) {
    IDo* a = getImplA();
    IDo* b = getImplB();
    
    a->print();
    b->print();

    delete b;
    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

```
// i_do.h
// interface file for DI
#pragma once

class IDo {
public:
    virtual ~IDo() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

```
// do_a.h
#pragma once
#include "i_do.h"

IDo *getImplA();
```

```
// do_b.h
#pragma once
#include "i_do.h"

IDo *getImplB();
```

```
// do_a.cpp
#include "do_a.h"
  
#include <iostream>

namespace { // adding anon-namespace seems to be another alternative

class Do : public IDo {
public:
    virtual void print() override {
        std::cout << "ImplA" << std::endl;
    }
};

} 

IDo* getImplA() {
    return new Do();
}
```

```
// do_b.cpp
#include "do_b.h"
  
#include <iostream>

namespace {

class Do : public IDo {
public:
    virtual void print() override {
        std::cout << "ImplB" << std::endl;
    }
};

}

IDo* getImplB() {
    return new Do();
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

# C++ version required
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
    "-std=gnu++2a -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -fexceptions -O0 -g3 ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}"
)

project(main)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(Main main)

set(MainSrc
    main.cpp
)

set(ApplSrc
    do_a.cpp
    do_a.h
    do_b.cpp
    do_b.h
    i_do.h
)

add_executable(${Main} ${ApplSrc} ${MainSrc})
```

Edited to wrap the class Do {...}; in an anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 0):

No way.

You use cout in both files and expect that to be the same object. So how would class Do be different types?

A namespace, any namespace, makes the names different, so of course that works.

I would name them DoA and DoB, and be done with it.

Comment: I was considering the object file to be somewhat separate, I was a little surprised there was not a message anywhere that stated the same class object existed in both object files. I guess it just takes the first it finds. After I gave it some thought it made sense, I had been naming them differently and then cut and pasted a quick test and was caught off guard.

Comment: An additional note, I added the namespace after the fact. Originally it was just the raw code and I half expected the source file to behave like it were in an anonymous namespace with something like cout being visible from a global namespace.

Comment: @Steven There is nothing special about source files vs headers, so *everything* from all include-files will also be in both object files. The only difference is that stuff from <iostream> will be identical everywhere, so that part works fine.